# show administration theme when editing page in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am using a custom theme for the front end of my **drupal** website.I created it by modifying garland theme.And I am using garland as the admin theme.

When I try to edit a page from admin it shows the edit page with my custom theme (http://example.com/node/2/edit?destination=admin%2Fcontent%2Fnode). And It breaks up the layout.

I want to show the admin theme for all the admin tasks. This problem also occurs on the blocks page (http://example.com/admin/build/block).

Is there any **custom module or core hack** to show admin theme when editing pages.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use admin theme by non-admin users you must give permissions to that user: Permitions->System->View the administration theme

Answer (score 4):

Be sure that you check the option in the page example.com/admin/settings/admin

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get the admin theme showing for non-admin users, I went to admin/people/permissions/list and checked the "View the administration theme" box for all roles.

Sounds simple except that the Filter list wasn't showing that entry when I typed theme, so it took me awhile to find it.  Finally I used the browser find to find all instances of the word "theme".

Or, you could type "System" in the Filter list to show only a few options in the relevant category.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [admin theme module,](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_theme) download and install it , the go to  permission in `dmin/people/permissions` then  in `Administration theme` set permission to waht user  you want by checking `Access administration theme`.
Then goto `http://chapboo.com/admin/appearance` in bottom of the page  in custom page add

```
admin/*
node/add/*
node/*/edit
```

and finally clear the cache

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the checkbox under:

exemple.com/admin/appearance

[image]